# Can I search multiple directories for files using wildcard in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Do I have to write a script for this or is there some other workaround/module that can do this?  For example can I use gci *.ptx with tree or some other command?  This is my first post so I apologize if I am not being clear or if my question is super basic!

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm.

Comment: This is very basic. It doesn't hurt to actually try yourself before asking. You used more time registering and writing this question than you did searching on Google. :-)

Comment: Actually not true I did try doing it myself using other methods but I am a beginner - I spent over two weeks trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

The below command is an example.

```
Get-ChildItem . file.* -Recurse
```

This will search the current directory recursively for files starting with `file.`

To generalize the format should be

```
Get-ChildItem path_to_look_for file_name_with_wildcar*s -option
```

The `*` as you expect will do the wildcard match, technically called file name expansion or *globbing*.

Also note that Get-ChildItem has following aliases :

```
gci
ls
dir
```

So

```
dir path_to_look_for file_name_with_wildcar*s -option
```

has the same effect

Comment: I noticed that the following also works: Get-ChildItem -Recurse *file*

Comment: @Clint : It should. Here you just change order of arguments. By default Get-ChildItem looks in the current directory. So if you don't explixitly give the path, it looks in the directory from where you execute the command.

Comment: Thank you @sjsam for your detailed answer!

Comment: @Clint : You may accept is as a token of encouragement :D